# HTML Image Layout Issue between 2 Label Controls

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table look utilizing CSS Divs, and Im having a problem inserting a transparent image between Label Controls, in order to give these Labels a decent amount of vertical space between them.  I want to accomplish the same for the TextBox Controls.

The problem is that this Image appears before all of the Label Controls when they should appear between each of the Label controls

I had already tried using:  `<br style="clear:both; line-height:50px;" />`

between each of the Labels which also did not work.

I would appreciate any solution or an alternative.

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="LeftLabelColumn">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" class="emaillable" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" class="emaillable" Text="Company:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
    </div>    
    <div id="RightControlColumn">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="contacttextbox"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="contacttextbox"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>

#contact {
    height:318px;
    width:848px;
    margin:6px 0 0 17px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    /*background-color:green;*/
}
#LeftLabelColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:orange;   
}
#RightControlColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:276px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}
.emaillabel {
    height:120px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom:125px;
} 
.linespace {
    height: 650px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: block;    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div id="contact">
    <div id="LeftLabelColumn" class="emaillabel">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="emaillable" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="emaillable" Text="Company:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="emaillable" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="emaillable" Text="Phone:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
    </div> 
    <div id="MidLabelColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="RightControlColumn">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="contacttextbox" Width="224px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />            
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="contacttextbox" Width="224px" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />            
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="contacttextbox" Width="224px" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
    </div>           
</div>

#contact {
    height:318px;
    width:848px;
    margin:6px 0 0 17px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
    /*background-color:green;*/
}
#LeftLabelColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:orange;   
}
#MidLabelColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;   
}
#RightControlColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:276px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}
.emaillabel {
    display: block;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    /*height: 200px;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
} 
.linespace {
    height: 25px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the labels and image in divs and put style="float:left" on each of the new divs

Comment: No I meant put each of the items in their own divs with float left

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `class="label"` to your markup

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name:" class="label"></asp:Label>
```

and then style it with css like so:

```
.label {margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

Comment: That didnt do anything. Do I still need to have the Image?

Comment: Try to add: .label {display: block; margin-bottom:10px;}

Comment: or try <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name:" class="label" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></asp:Label>

Comment: It would be better to do it with css but you could also code:
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Company:"></asp:Label>

Comment: I tried using 2 BR tags but the problem is that I need the same vertical distance for the Controls.  I can JSFiddle this.

Comment: Css is the best way to achieve this... I wonder why the above code is not working... still the floats do work...

Comment: Im using CSS, but Im not clear how to further refine this for each and every label and each and every control.  Ideas?  Unfortunately it appears that these ASP.NET Controls do not work in JSFiddle.

Comment: you can add a .label class to every label and style all of them with just one selector .label

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, style all of them with 1 selector

Comment: You can style multiple elements with the above css values if you assign the same class to all of them in your markup

eg:

<asp:Label ID="".... class="label">
<p class="label">Text</p>
<img src="... class="label" />

Comment: I updated the code to include a div class=linespace with a height of 650px, and this still does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#contact {
    height:318px;
    width:848px;
    margin:6px 0 0 17px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
#LeftLabelColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:orange;   
}
#MidLabelColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;   
}
#RightControlColumn {
    height:318px;
    width:276px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    padding-top:7px
} 

input
{
 width:224px;
}

.linespace {
    height: 25px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    clear:both; 
}</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="contact">
    <div id="LeftLabelColumn">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <label>Company:</label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
    </div> 
    <div id="MidLabelColumn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="RightControlColumn">
        <input class="contacttextbox"/>
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <input class="contacttextbox" />
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <input class="contacttextbox" />
        <div class="linespace"></div>
        <input class="contacttextbox" />
    </div>           
</div>

</body>
</html>
```